# javascript window.location id

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I want to make the browser to scroll the div's id

```
<div id="test">
   lol
</div>
```

So I use this code

```
window.location = "#test";
```

but my url now is like this

```
http://locahost/index.html#test
```

Is it possible to delete "#test" but go to that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll to the element:

```
document.querySelector('#test').scrollIntoView();
```